# How to import registered filters from one Django view to another?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with multiple modules.  I want to reuse filters I have created.

E.g. code: *main/views.py*

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
  def get_item(dictionary, key):
  return dictionary.get(key)

@register.filter
  def get_range(value):
  return range(value)
```

**(How) Can I import and use these filters (w/o cut and paste) in *secondary/views.py*?**

Comment: Please do *not* define tags in the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do *not* define tags in the `views.py`, but in a directory named `templatetags`. Indeed, the project tree should look like:

```
app/
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        tagname.py
    __init__.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

then you define the template tags and filters in `app/templatetags/tagname.py`:

```
# app/templatetags/tagname.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)

@register.filter
def get_range(value):
    return range(value)
```

and then you can load the template tags and filters with a `{% load … %}`:

```
{% load tagname %}

{{ mydict|get_item:mykey }}
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  But, will I need to import between apps, or can I load from one app into another?

Comment: @Van: yes, as long as you use `{% load tagname %}`, (and there are no overlaps in the names of the `.py` files), it will load these in the template engine in another application.